# Generate 'oneOf' property with operator-sdk

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

I'm currently a newcomer to the operator-sdk, however, I want to ask about something.

I'm trying to generate a CRD contained `oneOf` property in the spec. However, I got stuck in this task.

When I searched on google, I didn't find a way to implement the property using the operator-sdk.

If I wanted to implement generate the property `oneOf` as my CRD, is there any way to do it?

For example,

```
type: object
properties:
  spec:
    ...
    oneOf:
      - required: [someproperties1]
      - required: [someproperties2]
```

Thanks.

Comment: The operator-sdk uses the kubernetes-sigs/controller-tools to generate the CRDs and it appears there is an open issue an PR about this exact topic: [issue 461](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-tools/issues/461), [pr 298](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-tools/pull/298)

In general, this would be handled with the [code generation markers](https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/markers.html)

Comment: @JasonKincl Thanks for reply, as I saw issue and pr, It seems that i can find a way to implement the properties. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonKincl It seems that pr is not merged yet, so I cannot use the Oneof validation in kubebuilder. Is there any other mehods?

Answer (score -1):

Yes! Follow either the [Ansible, Helm or Go](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/build/) quickstart docs.

Assuming your question is about creating a CRD.

For example. if you are following the Go quickstart, you can use the [operator-sdk CLI like this](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/golang/quickstart/#add-a-new-custom-resource-definition):

```sh
$ operator-sdk add api --api-version=my.example.com/v1alpha1 --kind=OneOf
```

or with Ansible:

```sh
$ operator-sdk new my-operator --api-version=my.example.com/v1alpha1 --kind=OneOf --type=ansible
```

Note that your CRD needs to start with caps (K8s convention): `OneOf`

Now, if you want to define [a 'spec' in your CRD](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/golang/quickstart/#define-the-spec-and-status), you can also follow the quickstart guides (The boilerplate will be created by the `operator-sdk` CLI). For example for Go, it would be creating a struct in the code:

```golang
type OneOfSpec struct {
    // Size is the size of your OneOf
    Size int32 `json:"size"`
}
type OneOfStatus struct {
    // Nodes are the names of the oneof pods
    Nodes []string `json:"nodes"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!! I could understand implementing CRDs with `opertaor-sdk`. However I wanted to know about implement specific methods of `oneOf`  properties in 'spec'(usually?). Is there any guidelines?

Comment: Did you run? `make generate` after you defined your types? as it says here: https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/golang/quickstart/#define-the-spec-and-status did you look at how other community operators are implemented?

Comment: Actually, I tried the way which above comments written by @JasonKincl, however it seems that pr is not merged yet. Frankly speaking, I am not trying to generate 'oneOf' CRD, but I want to generate 'oneOf' property in CRD spec.

Comment: yes. in the example above, size and nodes are properties. Your controller code will have to decide what to do with those properties.

Comment: ahah. Sorry for my bad english. It is not a properties what I want. I wanted to implement something like example above. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: yes. there are quite a bit of examples you can follow online

Comment: Can I get some advices or links, I can follow? Actually I search lots of ways, but I failed to implement mm..

Comment: this one https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk-samples/tree/master/go/memcached-operator